# How to clear Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to open an old android project but the build keeps failing with two errors,
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'TabianConsulting'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        project :

Comment: Check your internet connection, maybe you need to use VPN

Comment: Also try invalidate caches/restart